# Calculating $\displaystyle{\int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t}dt}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I was studying Fourier Transform; I could answer to this $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t}dt$$ by Fourier Transform, but I have problem in $$\int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t}dt.$$ I would be grateful if you help me to get the point of this integral.

Comment: So you want to integrate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-jwt}dt.$$

Answer (score 3):

It's the Fourier transform of the Heaviside step function (which is zero for $x<0$). It only exists in the sense of distributions. Does it help if I point you to entry number 313 in [Wikipedia's table of transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions)?

Comment: the Fourier transform actually exists for $\text{Im}\, \omega < 0$.

Comment: @Fabian: Sure, but when one says "Fourier transform" rather than "two-sided Laplace transform" it is usually understood that $\omega$ is a real number.

Comment: I was not aware of the difference. For me Laplace and Fourier transform is all the same just a bit rotated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\text{Im}\,\omega<0$ (for convergence), you can calculate the integral easily
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t}dt = \frac{e^{-i\omega t}}{-i \omega} \biggl|_{t= 0}^{\infty} = \frac{i}{\omega}.$$

As some people want to use the fourier transform for $\omega$ on the real line, they write 
$$\frac{i}{\omega - i 0^+}$$ where the $0^+$ reminds them that the original integral was only defined for $\omega$ in the lower half plane.

At some point, you might learn about [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) (which Hans Lundmark was referring to) and then you can use the [Sokhatsky-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhatsky%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) and rewrite it as
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t}dt = \mathcal{P}\frac{i}{\omega} - \pi \delta(\omega).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.I'm thinking and studying to learn what you mentioned about Sokhatsky Theorem and distributions.